# Div at the top of the page before other top divs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to force secondClass before firstClass even if first class has the same top value ?
If possible with jquery or just css hack. The value of firstClass could be different than in this example, but the value of the secondClass is fixed.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="firstClass">Hello</div>
        <div class="secondClass">This is Warning!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and css

```
.firstClass {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

.secondClass {
    position: fixed;
    top: -25px;
}
```

Online demo http://jsfiddle.net/AQUgk/

Thank you.

Comment: can't you have the first just start from say 30px and leave the above space for messages like 'This is warning'.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the actual use is parsed page, where we should inform that this page is not ours. that's why I dont the actual css. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To just move it on screen with CSS:

```
$(".firstClass").css('top', $(".secondClass").height());
$(".secondClass").css('top', 0);
```

If moving the elements in the DOM is what you'r after:

```
$(".firstClass").before($(".secondClass"));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/AQUgk/2/)

Comment: Thank you, but how to force secondClass at the bottom even if firstclass undefined!

Comment: First you want to have secondClass before firstClass, now you'd like to have secondClass at the bottom. At the bottom of what, the screen, the element, or below an element that is not defined ?

Comment: Then just set it to `$(".secondClass").css('bottom', 0);`